# how to select a specific field for multiple tables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three model `Admin`,`User`,`Post`

`Admin` model contain `id`,`email`,`password`

`User` model contain `id`,`email`,`password`,`admin_id`

`Post` model contain `id`,`name`,`admin_id`

I need to select all name of `Post` when `admin_id` in `User` is `==` `admin_id` in `Post`

Comment: What is Foluser?

Comment: @Waheed sorry i wrong . edit post `Foluser` is `user`

Comment: Would collect the name of the posts in an array be fine?

Comment: @Asarluhi what's you mean?

Comment: I mean if you would like to have the names of each post in an array, such as `[name-1, name-2, ... , name-n]`

Answer (score 1):

as your information above, your table schema seems like this

```
admin has_many users
admin has_many posts
```

now to get all post when admin_id in user == admin_id in post you can use joins

```
@posts = Post.joins(admin: :users).
          select("post.*, users.email as user_email").
          where("posts.admin_id = users.admin_id")

@posts.first.name is equal to name of first post
@posts.first.user_email is equal to email in user table
```

joins will generate sql INNER JOIN between these 3 tables, then you select which column that you want to show with select as an example code above I'm using users.email as user_email, user_email is an alias name so you can access directly using @posts.first.user_email

Answer (score 0):

This should work for whatever association you have on your models. Try this:

```
Post.where('admin_id IN (?)', User.pluck(:admin_id)).pluck(:name)
```